# Speed calculation from Range Rate and Bearing Rate

Tags: physics, radar-chart

In terms of Radar Theory if I have the Range Rate and Bearing(Azimuth) Rate of a target, then can its real speed be calculated ?

Comment: i think you're on the wrong forum for that question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics/physics, not coding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming

Answer (score 1):

No, not without more information.

Suppose a target has a range rate of zero and a bearing rate of 0.75 radian/second. It could be a cheetah 40 meters away, or an object in the vicinity of the moon, traveling at the speed of light.

Comment: reading this made my day

Answer (score -1):

You are right ANJANU, with a zero range rate the target would be flying in a perfect circle around the RADAR site. To calculate to speed of the target you would need to know the rotational rate of the RADAR which would give you the degree/second and/or radians/second. Most RADAR data is in ACP's which is 4096 per rotation which can be converted to radians per second.
You would also need the direction of travel of the target in relation to the rotation of the RADAR i.e. whether the aircraft is traveling in the direction of rotation or against the direction of rotation. You would also need the distance from the RADAR site even though the rate of change is zero.
Hope this gets you started. By the way, Mr McK is no Dr. McKay and the reason NASA normally doesn't hire Computer science majors fresh out of college.